# Evaluate $(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2})^5 + (2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2})^5$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My question says:

> Without using tables, find the value of
> $$\left(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5 + \left(2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5$$

I have said:

$$\left(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) = 2\left(1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)$$

$$\implies\left(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5 = 2^5\left(1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^5$$

$$\left(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5 = 2^5\Bigg(1 + \frac{5}{2\sqrt2} + \frac{5\cdot4}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^2 + \frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^3 + \frac{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{4!}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^4 + \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^5\Bigg)$$

Similarly,

$$\left(2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5 = 2^5\Bigg(1 - \frac{5}{2\sqrt2} + \frac{5\cdot4}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^2 - \frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^3 + \frac{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{4!}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^4 -\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\right)^5\Bigg)$$

Adding gives,

$$\left(2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5 + \left(2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^5 = 32\left(2 + \frac{5}{2} + \frac{5}{64}\right) = 146.5$$

But my text book says the answer is $149$.

Have I adopted the wrong approach or have I merely slipped up somewhere? I have checked my working several times.

Comment: It may be simpler to use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Two_Fifth_Powers

Comment: How did you get $5/64$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure your solution was close to perfect but I think you put that $(\frac{5*4*3*2}{4!}(\frac{1}{2*\sqrt{2}})^4) *2$  is $\frac{5}{64}$ but in reality it is $\frac{5}{32}$. Fix that and your solution gives you 149.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use algebra:

If $a=2+\dfrac1{\sqrt2},b=2-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

$a+b=4, ab=\dfrac72$

$$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=?$$

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)=?$$

$$(a^3+b^3)(a^2+b^2)=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Since$$\sum_\pm(a\pm b)^5=2\left(a^5+\binom{5}{2}a^3b^2+\binom{5}{4}ab^4\right)$$you want$$2a_5=2\left(2^5+10\cdot2^3/\sqrt{2}^2+5\cdot2/\sqrt{2}^4\right)=149.$$

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to multiply the last term by $2$. It should be
$$32\left(2+\frac52+\frac{5}{32}\right)=\boxed{149}$$
as expected.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)